# How to apply a rolling window (using `rolling`) on `SeriesGroupBy` pandas object of `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a a data frame which I grouped by a column to get `dfDatGrp` which is of type `DataFrameGroupBy`.

I select a specific column by `dfDatGrp['Time']` to create `SeriesGroupBy` with `dtype: datetime64[ns]`:

```py
12615   2021-11-21 19:18:00
22797   2021-11-21 19:18:00
24765   2021-11-21 19:19:00
14819   2021-11-21 19:21:00
20953   2021-11-21 19:23:00
```

Now, I am trying to apply a filter using `rolling()`:

```py
dfDatGrp['Time'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], raw = True)
```

I get an error: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. Probably it has something to do with the `dtype` of the series. Is there a way to to make it behave like a numeric type?

#### Recreate the Data Frame

This will create a sample of the case:

```py
dfData = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'B': np.random.randn(5), 'Time': ['2021-11-21 19:18:00', '2021-11-21 19:18:00', '2021-11-21 19:19:00', '2021-11-21 19:21:00', '2021-11-21 19:23:00']})

dfData['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfData['Time'], infer_datetime_format = 'True')
dfDataGrp = dfData.groupby('A')
dfDataGrp['Time'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], raw = True)
```

The output should match to:

```py
for grpName, dfGroup in dfDataGrp:

    vIndx = dfGroup.index

    for ii, idxVal in enumerate(vIndx):
        if ii == 0:
            continue

        dfData.loc[idxVal, 'Diff Time'] = (dfData.loc[idxVal, 'Time'] - dfData.loc[vIndx[ii - 1], 'Time']).total_seconds()
```

Which results in:

```py
   A         B                Time  Diff Time
0  0 -0.549114 2021-11-21 19:18:00        NaN
1  1  0.137590 2021-11-21 19:18:00        NaN
2  0 -0.020969 2021-11-21 19:19:00       60.0
3  1 -0.328425 2021-11-21 19:21:00      180.0
4  0  0.552618 2021-11-21 19:23:00      240.0
```

Namely the output should be a series (The column `Diff Time`).

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your original DataFrame and the code to get `dfDatGrp`?

Comment: @not_speshal, I added something.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @not_speshal, Per group, I'd like to have the time difference between successive data.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
dfData["Diff Time"] = dfData.groupby("A")["Time"].diff().dt.total_seconds()

>>> dfData

   A         B                Time  Diff Time
0  0 -1.038956 2021-11-21 19:18:00        NaN
1  1  0.503860 2021-11-21 19:18:00        NaN
2  0  0.230071 2021-11-21 19:19:00       60.0
3  1  0.331492 2021-11-21 19:21:00      180.0
4  0  0.400699 2021-11-21 19:23:00      240.0
```

Comment: Bu the idea is to run this withing a group as in `dfDataGrp`.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: The output should be a series which is equivalent to the time difference between successive rows. Please start by working on `dfDataGrp['Time'].rolling(2)` then you'll see.

Comment: Look at the edited answer. If that's not what you need, post the expected output as a table in your question.

Comment: I have posted expected output. Think of a rolling difference. I want per group find the time difference between successive elements in the `Time` column.

Comment: You don't need `rolling` at all. Since you mention "successive elements". See the edit

Comment: That's great! Just for the sake of knowledge, how can it be achieved with `apply()`?